# How can I collate and summarize records from a file with Perl?

Tags: perl, sed, awk, unix

I have a text file in the following format:

```
211B1 CUSTOMER|UPDATE|  
211B2 CUSTOMER|UPDATE|  
211B3 CUSTOMER|UPDATE|  
211B4 CUSTOMER|UPDATE|  
211B5 CUSTOMER|UPDATE|  
567FR CUSTOMER|DELETE|  
647GI CUSTOMER|DELETE|
```

I want a script that processes the text file and reports the following:

- "UPDATE" for column CUSTOMER found for Acct's: 211B1,211B2,211B3,211B4,211B5
- "DELETE" for column CUSTOMER found for Acct's: 5675FR,6470GI

I can script simple solutions, but this seems a little complex to me and would appreciate assistance or guidance.

Answer (score 6):

### collate.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my %actions;
while (<>) {
    my ($key, $fld, $action) = /^(\w+) (.+?)\|(.+?)\|/ or die "Failed on line $.!";
    push @{$actions{$action}{$fld}}, $key;
}

foreach my $action (keys %actions) {
    foreach my $fld (keys %{$actions{$action}}) {
        print "\"$action\" for column $fld found for Acct's: " . join(",", @{$actions{$action}{$fld}}), "\n";
    }
}
```

Use like so:

```
perl collate.pl < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Wow, you guys are fantastic!  This worked exactly as I wanted. Thanks!  This is a great site and the speed of response is unbelievable...

Comment: You're welcome David. Response times actually vary quite a bit, but everyone races to solve "cute little problems" like this. :)

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
echo '211B1 CUSTOMER|UPDATE|  
211B2 CUSTOMER|UPDATE|  
211B3 CUSTOMER|UPDATE|  
211B4 CUSTOMER|UPDATE|  
211B5 CUSTOMER|UPDATE|  
567FR CUSTOMER|DELETE|  
647GI CUSTOMER|DELETE|' | awk -F '[ |]' '
    BEGIN {
        upd="";del=""
    } {
      if ($3 == "UPDATE") {upd = upd" "$1};
      if ($3 == "DELETE") {del = del" "$1};
    } END {
        print "Updates:"upd; print "Deletes:"del
    }'
```

produces:

```
Updates: 211B1 211B2 211B3 211B4 211B5
Deletes: 567FR 647GI
```

It basically just breaks each line into three fields (with the `-F` option) and maintains a list of updates and deletes that it appends to, depending on the "command".

The `BEGIN` and `END` are run before and after all line processing so they're initialization and the final output.

I'd put it into a script to make it easier. I left it as a command line tool just since that's how I usually debug my awk scripts.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    next unless $line =~ /\S/;
    my ($acct, $col, $action) = split /\s|\|/, $line;
    push @{ $data{$action}->{$col} }, $acct;
}

for my $action ( keys %data ) {
    for my $col ( keys %{ $data{$action} } ) {
        print qq{"$action" for column $col found for acct's: },
              join q{,}, @{ $data{$action}->{$col} }, "\n";    
    }

}
__DATA__
211B1 CUSTOMER|UPDATE|  
211B2 CUSTOMER|UPDATE|  
211B3 CUSTOMER|UPDATE|  
211B4 CUSTOMER|UPDATE|  
211B5 CUSTOMER|UPDATE|  
567FR CUSTOMER|DELETE|  
647GI CUSTOMER|DELETE|
```

Answer (score 0):

another awk version, though does reverse order of code values, and has an extra "," at end of each line

```
BEGIN { FS="[ |]" }

{
        key = $3 " for column " $2
        MAP[ key ] = $1 "," MAP[ key ]
}

END {
        for ( item in MAP ) {
                print item " found for Acct's: " MAP[ item ]
        }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Based on your question, you could do this:

```
perl -i.bak -pe'if(/^211B[1-5]/){s/CUSTOMER/UPDATE/}elsif(/^(5675FR|6470GI)/){s/CUSTOMER/DELETE/}' filename
```

Though I notice now that the last two account numbers differ in the example, and also that the second column already has those values...

Comment: Huh? That just reproduces the input, changing the "CUSTOMER" to "UPDATE" for the first few lines and to "DELETE" for the last few. -1.

Comment: From rereading the question, I now see what happened -- the OP used the word "reformat", which you interpreted to mean that he wanted a kind of search-and-replace operation. But actually it was bad wording on his part -- he wanted to summarise the information, not "reformat" it. (I've now reworded it.) I'm gonna leave the -1 sorry (harsh I know) because your solution doesn't solve the right problem.

Comment: What an idiot I've been. I've been answering what the OP asks. This should teach a lesson.

Comment: @Anonymous: It's generous to say that the original question was ambiguous -- the other 3 responders had no trouble inferring what the OP actually wanted. But have a good cry if it makes you feel better.

Comment: Thank you for that advice. I need direction, and now I have someone to emulate.